# Bootstrap: How do I remove hover effect in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap for my website with a link that opens a new tab. In my desktop browser, the link remains focused(red) after I close the tab(without moving my mouse pointer in the window).

I added `onclick="this.blur()` to remove the focus(red), but `hover` is still in effect(green).

How to I remove both focus and hover?

CSS file:

```
a {
  color:black;
}
a:hover {
  color:green;
}
a:focus {
  color:red;
}
```

HTML file:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" onclick="this.blur();">google</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

simply override it in CSS using the same color as the link,

```css
a, a:hover, a:focus{
  color:black;
}
```

and if you want, you can override `:visited` and `:active` too

```css
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active, a:focus{
  color:black;
}
```

---

Here is a snippet

```css
a,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:active,
a:focus {
  color: black !important;
}

/*important used for demo only*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
```

Comment: I needed hover and focus with a color other than black.

Comment: I tried the example from bootply and it doesn't work. The link will remain green in a visited state. Not sure if you understand my question. When I hover over the link, it should be a different color other than black. After a click on the link, it will turn back to black. Another thing I would like to point out is that if I don't open a new tab using "_blank", I would go to the linked page and pressing on the back button would bring me back to my initial page where the link is returned black(since focus and hover will be lost, which doesn't happen if I open a new tab).

Comment: you just have to change the colors to whatever you like the most,

Comment: If I changed visited to black, hover will be black, which doesn't really solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
a:active, visited {
  color:black;
}
```

`active` is the state a link has after you clicked it. You won't loose the hover effect in this case.

Comment: I tried the code you provided and it doesn't work. I'm using chrome browser where I open a new tab after clicking the link. My example only works if I going to a new page and return(since it resets hover and focus).